# AWS API gateway + SQS + Lambda + get response back from Lambda to API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I want to use API Gateway to send a message to SQS which then needs to trigger Lambda. After calculations are finished within Lambda, I need to pass the results back to API Gateway. In other words, something like this:

```
Get request --> Gateway API --> SQS --> Lambda --> (back to the same SQS?) -->  Gateway API
```

I have setup all the necessary permissions meaning that I can call Gateway API and send message to SQS which then sends that to Lambda (I can see in the Cloudwatch that Lambda received the message). However, I cannot get the Lambda response back to Gateway API...

Does anybody has some advice/tutorial/blog post about that? I have watched various youtube videos and searched posts on SO but didn't find solution for my problem.

Comment: Your flow is asyn from SQS -> Lambda. If you need to get response, Gateway API -> Lambda so you can get response from Lambda.

Comment: If you want API Gateway to wait for the response, why are you using SQS?

Comment: @NghiaDo So let me see if understand. I have to have then two methods inside my API gateway, one is POST to my SQS and another one is GET from Lambda? I need to call API Gateway twice?

Comment: @MarkB Because I have been advised to use SQS in case of many requests per second (for example potentially >500 in 1 second). Should I do that at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS Lambda can handle a large number of concurrent invocations. The default is 1000 (one thousand) and can be increased via a support ticket [to "Hundreds of thousands"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).

If you want to use SQS to *smoothen* intermittent request spikes, then the Lambda function invocations will be asynchronous with respect to the caller's/client's API Gateway call and you need to use other means to feedback the Lambda invocation result to the API Gateway caller/client.

One such possibility can be a callback URL that your Lambda will invoke on the caller's/client's side once it has processed the invocation. Or you can store the lambda invocation result somewhere (such as S3 or DynamoDB) and the caller/client can use polling to periodically ask for the invocation result (check whether it is ready and if so, retrieve it).

Either way, once you use SQS to *decouple* API Gateway invocations from the processing of those invocations by your Lambda function via SQS messages, then the processing of the Lambda invocations will be *asynchronous* to the API Gateway caller/client request. So, the HTTP request of the API Gateway caller/client will return right away without waiting for the Lambda invocation result.

Comment: Great answer, this clarifies things a lot. So if I can ensure that Lambda handles 100s of requests per second in synchronous manner (FIFO) than I don't need to use SQS. Thank you!